# Ubuntu 18.04 Dual Screen Not Working on new Dell G5 15 in my main account

Tags: monitor

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. It was working very well with the nvidia drivers but suddenly (I don't know if maybe after an update) the dual monitor function stopped working in my main account but it works in the guest account. How do you think i can solve the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you had any luck with your problem? I'm experiencing the same here...

Comment: I had it working, thanks to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122013/set-up-external-monitor-for-laptop/1124870?noredirect=1#comment1861692_1124870. Only difference is that I had to use this PPA (https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to install a valid version of the drivers (396)