# set up external monitor for laptop

Tags: 18.04, dell, laptop, multiple-monitors, gnome-settings-daemon

I am trying to set up a second monitor for my Dell G5 laptop.
Ubuntu version 18.04 LTS.
However, I am struck at this:

[image: settings/devices/screen Display]

What I tried so far is:
Download Gnome-Tweak-Tool and selected workspaces spans display.
reinstall gnome setting using the command line

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

None works. can someone help me out?

output of `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080    120.00*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Update: 2019/03/11
I tried installing newer Nvidia drivers and tested several of them. It did not work, and the latest one broke my resolution and refresh-rate setting, even after I reverted the driver.
I tried reinstalling Ubuntu from a flash drive. However, that did not work either. It fixed the resolution/refresh-rate problem, but not the original problem. back to square one.

Comment: Did you enable external monitor by Fn+Fx keys?

Comment: @VIN what is happening on your screen when you Press Super+P key and release only P and press again

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried, but nothing happen. I try restarting the monitor, and it returns 'no signal'. I also try doing it with window and that worked.

Comment: @PRATAP no response at all

Comment: what is the output of `xrandr`

Comment: does your laptop have 2 HDMI ports? are you trying to connect the monitor with HDMI?

Comment: @PRATAP it has 1 HDMI and 1 Thunderbolt ports. I am trying to connect through HDMI

Comment: your monitor have input of only HDMI or also DVI and VGA?

Comment: @PRATAP it also has VGA

Comment: can you check if the input it is taking is not VGA instead of HDMI or is it in Auto mode..

Comment: if you observe the output you pasted in Question.. last lines..the status is showing disconnected for both the HDMI's.. the signals are not going at all to monitor..

Comment: Looking deeper. I do not seem to even have ~/.config/monitors.xml.

Comment: Have you found any solution to make it work?

Comment: @BriceP no, I am still trying

Comment: @VIN ok, thanks anyway. If I find anything, I'll come here to tell you. Please do so too!

Comment: I fixed it @BriceP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is Secure Boot. It blocks some files from being installed properly.
You don't have to disable it though. Go to 'Software & Updates' -> 'Additional Drivers' and enable the open source 'X.Org X Server...' driver (temporary). then purge the Nvidia driver.

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```

make sure that it is gone

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

Go back to 'Software & Updates' and reselect the Nvidia driver.
it will ask you to set up a Secure Boot password. do that.
Apply and restart.

Before you got booted into the log in screen there will a blue screen with  'press any key to perform MOK management', do that. Choose 'enrol key from disk', put in you password. Then navigate your way out (I forgot what happened next, but it is very simple). Reboot ... and check if it works.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. But it didn't for me... It never asked to set up secure boot password. And after, with and without activating secure boot (which wasn't on by default), it doesn't work. And in "About", it shows Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2), it doesn't mention Nvidia at all. There is a difference though: I'm runnin Ubuntu 18.10, and I bougth the machine with Ubuntu only (which may be why secure boot wasn't enabled by default).

Comment: This only work if you have a Nvidia card, but. A good way to see where things goes wrong is to go to the terminal, type in 'nvidia-settings' and see if there is any errors pop up @BriceP

Comment: Your comment led me to the solution! I added an external PPA (https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) which allowed me to install a newer version of the drivers (396 in my case). After that I had the same messages about the enrolling as you, so I obeyed, and it worked!

Comment: @BriceP the same was happening to me, I've never been asked for a MOK password. But after I've used this command sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key the system guided me to set up a password. Now everything work fine. More information here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot