# No External Monitor After Install

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, thinkpad, external-monitor

I've just installed Ubuntu onto my Thinkpad p51 and I'm trying to connect my external monitor.

The frustrating thing is that it worked perfectly when booting from the live USB installer.  I didn't have to do anything, it just worked!  However, after installing Ubunutu I get 'no signal' detected.  I've tried using my mini-display port (which is what was working with the install USB and Windows10) and my HDMI (which also works with Windows)

I do have an nvidia card (Quadro m2200)  I can get to the nvidia settings and the drivers in settings show the card is working!

Not quite ready to ditch Windows so this is a dual boot setup (not sure if that matters)

I did find this thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122013/set-up-external-monitor-for-laptop).

After trying all of the steps I've still got no monitor!

I'm totally new to Linux but I really like the idea.  My studio might be moving to Linux and I'd really like to get ahead of the curve... but if I can't even get my external monitor working I'm not too confident in using it as my primary OS.

Any ideas appreciated!

**UPDATE**
I decided to try again but this time without installing the 3rd party drivers at install.  Seems to be working w/my external monitor.  My quadro card isn't showing up in the system info (which is expected).  Makes me think that it's definitely some issue with the nvidia driver.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release did you install? Did you install Nvidia drivers? Tru to disable Windows fast start feature and reboot to Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  I installed the Nvidia drivers (using the 'install 3rd party drivers' option while installing Ubuntu.

I decided to erase and try again but this time without installing 3rd party drivers and it's working!  I would really like to have the Nvidia driver working since I'll be using 3d apps like Houdini and Nuke but if not needed then I'm good!  Also, I killed fast start before installing!

Answer (score 0):

Aha!  Not sure if this is remotely useful for anyone else but I got it working...

1. Clean install - no 3rd party drivers
2. Verified external monitor was working (quadro card not showing up as gpu, using intel)
3. Manually selected the latest driver from Nvidia in driver settings
4. I was prompted with MOK setup! (this is new)
5. Rebooted and selected 'enroll' keys
6. Tada!

The link I referenced got me most of the way there but manually uninstalling all the nvidia after the fact didn't work for me (100% user error)  Clean install seems to have done the trick!

Comment: The 20.04 is the first release that installs Nvidia drivers from scratch. Maybe there is some bug with that. Previously there was no such option.